# gw text wrapping for LaTeX

Tags: filetype-tex, wrapping

Is there an easy way to wrap LaTeX source? Using `gwip` is great for individual paragraphs,

```latex
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

...but it fails more generally for other situations such as itemize environments:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua.
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}
```

Or captions:

```latex
\begin{figure}
  \caption[Lorem ipsum]{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
    fugiat nulla pariatur.%
  }
\end{figure}
```

Issues:

- Using `gw` in visual mode is not very fast. (`gwip` with the `ip` text-object is far easier and doesn't require manual selection.)
- Using `textwidth=80` is great for auto-wrapping when writing a fresh paragraph, but not very helpful when editing text in the middle of a paragraph.
- Autowrapping within a middle of a paragraph can be accomplished with `set formatoptions+=a`, but that also ends up wrapping everything *after* the paragraph too:

  ```latex
  \begin{figure}
    \caption[Lorem ipsum]{%
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua.% } \end{figure}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plug-in can help here.

Among its [features](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/README.md#features) you'll find it support custom text objects:

> - `ic ac` Commands
> - `id ad` Delimiters
> - `ie ae` LaTeX environments
> - `i$ a$` Inline math structures
> - `iP aP` Sections

In your case, it seems to me that `gwie` would do what you're looking for, selecting the text inside an environment, which is the block delimited by `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`.

If you also install the [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plug-in, you can enable additional text objects for environments, see [targets-textobj-cheatsheet.md](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/targets-textobj-cheatsheet.md).